# Text Hover Reveals Image Behind (z-index) - what's the issue?

Tags: html, css, hover

The goal is to have the image show up BEHIND the text upon hover. I've tried several different scenarios, but the z-index doesn't take.

Here is the site: http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/artists/

```css
.artisthover {
  display: none
}

h2.two:hover img {
  display: block;
  z-index: -5;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="two">
  <h2>ALBERT DALTON</h2>
  <img src="http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Weary_Thumb.jpg" class="artisthover">
</h2>
```

What am I missing?

Comment: your class selector is not correct! that's whats wrong. and for the z-index to work you need to add position to the container

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In order to the z-index to work it needs a position different than static. Add `position: relative;` to the img and you'll get it to work.

```
h2.two:hover img {
  display: block;
  z-index: -5;
  position: relative;
}
```

You could also add `z-index` to the h2 if you want the picture over the text:

```
h2.two {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: of course, thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

its not using Z-index but by using CSS background image this can be done easily

```css
h2:hover {
  height: 200px;
  background-image: url('http://lawnyavawnya.com/2018/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Weary_Thumb.jpg');
  background-position: 0px 15px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>ALBERT DALTON</h2>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant nest h2 inside h2 because the like adding h3 inside h2 the second heading will be displayed smaller in some browsers.

`z-index` works with positioned elements only.

check this code see how it works:

```css
.artisthover {
 display: none;
}

h2.two:hover img {
  position: relative;
 display: block;
 z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<h2 class="two">
ALBERT DALTON
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/1000" class="artisthover">
</h2>
```